# Filtering sorted array with a defined threshold in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a sorted list, for example `x = [120, 99, 90, 90, 40, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1]`.
I want to find the index of the last element that is greater than a variable, for example `limit = 30`. In this example, I want to get 4, because that's the index of 40 (and 5 is lower than 30).
How can I do that efficiently in python?
I can do looping like this:

```
def filtering(x, limit):
    for i,elem in enumerate(x):
       if elem <=limit:
          return i-1
    return i
```

But I was thinking if there is any better way / numpy function to do this. Thanks!

Comment: If it's already sorted, then use binary search

Comment: Will the array always be sorted? If yes, you can use binary search to this in `O(log n)` time instead of `O(n)`

Comment: it's always sorted from high to low

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned NumPy:

```
def last_ind(arr, limit):
    length = len(arr)
    sorter = np.arange(length)[::-1]
    pos = np.searchsorted(arr, limit, sorter=sorter)
    return length - pos - 1
```

Since `searchsorted` looks for an array sorted in *ascending* order but yours is sorted in descending order, we pass the indices of the list reversed to it with `sorter`. Also, `searchsorted` does the finding but it returns the index that you'd put the new number on; you, however, need the index of the previous element, hence -1. Lastly, since `searchsorted` worked as if it was sorted other way around, we correct the position by subtracting it from the length at the end.

Also, it returns -1 when no element in array is larger than the limit.

Sample runs:

```
>>> x
[120, 99, 90, 90, 40, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1]

>>> last_ind(x, 30)
4

>>> last_ind(x, 100)
0

>>> last_ind(x, 92)
1

>>> last_ind(x, 90)
3

>>> last_ind(x, 3)
7

>>> last_ind(x, 500)
-1

>>> last_ind(x, -51)
9
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use numpy

```
>>> x = np.array([120, 99, 90, 90, 40, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1])
>>> np.where(x > 30)
(array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]),)
```

The last returned element is the index you are looking for.